# What are the most common beginner mistakes when learning Blender?

Tags: modeling

I haven't found a question like this after a few searches. A lot of questions that come in are from beginners who are learning on their own. I know from experience what that is like, and how long it is before the sheer complexity and scope of Blender stop being very confusing. I don't know how many times I searched arduously to figure out how to undo something that was the result of one mistaken keystroke or click, or how often things have had to be rebuilt after an unnoticed mistake caused bad geometry.

I believe the most common mistakes are quantifiable and not a matter of opinion. I think it would be a real service to have the most common ones explained to beginners so they can be aware of them from the outset. I don't know of anywhere with such a guide. Maybe there is something like this here already and I didn't find it, if not, I hope this is considered not too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: I think this is indeed too broad... I think common mistakes are a mix of different learning styles and a lot of misinformation, mixed terminology and difficulties understanding the logic of tools (compunded with a confusing manual that is never up to date with the changes in the program).  I tried to compile frequently asked questions on this site (https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/frequently-asked-questions-on-blender-stack-exchange) and there was a similar attempt here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/867/helpful-post-reference-index

Comment: @cegaton Aha! See, i've been around here for a while, and went looking for that too and didn't find it.  Didn't think to look on Meta.

Comment: 99% of questions here are  "How to do something" , just a small amount is in the form: "This is broken, help!". The objective statistic that can be pulled from the site is about what knowledge people seek most, not what mistakes they make most. Also **there are no beginner mistakes, everything is a learning experience**.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I don't know about that, a look at the front page right now seems to be about 10% to 20% "This is broken, help" questions. And sure, it's all a learning experience, but knowing some key things can allow one to move on to more interesting learning experiences much faster.

Comment: I've bookmarked those two lists, they are very helpful. Maybe i'll come across something i can add or update.

Comment: That is true, but most of the obvious questions are answered on this site, and people who can search get the answer. If you order by popularity or vote count, it looks much different. With every *Help* question thousands more will view a *How to* question. Helping someone to overcome the common mistakes encountered in the beginning doesn't help him from quitting on the later encountered non-common mistakes, it's about the will to overcome. The solution is not about easing the first 4 bumps on the road, but easing all the bumps to allow people that drive with bad suspension to use the software.

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate Stack Exchange question.  It is an appropriate forum discussion question.  It is both overly broad and too subject to opinion.  However, I think that https://www.lifewire.com/common-pitfalls-of-beginning-modelers-2052 has a great short list that I would advise any beginning modeller to read and think about.

Answer (score 2):

- Double Vertices - Most often caused by extruding something, cancelling the move afterwards, and then extruding again. Can be fixed by selecting all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, and choosing 'Remove Doubles'.
- Flipped Normals - This can have many causes. It's visible as odd shading on a model, but is often a bit hard to pick out. Can be fixed by selecting all, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
- Unapplied Rotation and Scale - If the scale of an object is not 1 or its rotation is not 0 degrees on all axes, a lot of actions can have strange results. Unless there is a specific reason not to apply rotation or scale, can be fixed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and selecting the appropriate option.
- Hidden things - Pressing <kbd>H</kbd> makes whatever is selected invisible. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> unhides things.
- Unnessesary Ngons - Faces with more than 4 connected vertices (Ngons) may cause shading issues, and should be minimized. Ctrl + T triangulates the mesh, and can help avoid these problems.